# Recursive String Parser

Tags: java, string, parsing, recursion, substring

I need to create a program that recursively parses a string into smaller substrings. Every substring is one letter shorter than the previous; once it's at the end it would redisplay the word, but with the first letter sliced off, and then substrings of that.

For example: Given the word 'Slugger' the program would display

> Slugger
>   Slugge
>   Slugg
>   Slug
>   Slu
>   Sl
>   S
>   lugger
>   lugge
>   lugg
>   lug
>   lu
>   l

And on and on.

This is part of my code so far that is supposed to break things up:

```
private static void stringParser(String str)
{
    if(str.length() < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(str.length() == 0)
    {
        removeFirstChar(str, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(str);
        stringParser(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
    }
}   // End stringParser method

private static void removeFirstChar(String str, int i)
{
    String strNew = str.substring(i);
    stringParser(strNew);
    return strNew;
}   // End removeFirstChar method
```

I think I've got all the pieces and parts that I need, but perhaps just don't have them in the right order to do what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: This question is a little broad... Stack Overflow isn't supposed to do the heavy lifting for you; it's more if you have a specific question about your code that you're stuck on. Is there some kind of behavior you're looking for that you're missing? It sounds like you haven't tried running it yourself, the way your question is currently worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the following in your code. See if this works

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "slugger";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        stringParser(str.substring(i)); 
    }


    }
```

Complete code.....

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "slugger";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        stringParser(str.substring(i)); 
    }


    }

    private static void stringParser(String str)
    {
        if(str.length() < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if(str.length() == 0)
        {
            removeFirstChar(str, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(str);
            stringParser(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
        }
    }   // End stringParser method

    private static void removeFirstChar(String str, int i)
    {
        String strNew = str.substring(i);
        stringParser(strNew);
        str = strNew;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Awesome it worked excellently! All I needed was that for-loop in the main. Thank you so much! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks and that was a good code. Also please accept the answer if it solves your purpose.